# Snapping dangling nodes with prescribed angle using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I have got a streets shape file, to snap the dangling nodes in ARCGIS. 
[image]
But, I have to snap only some nodes(of feature) with a prescribed angle (green node in the image, and the angle marked in grey). And the other features (marked in red) has to be left out.

Any preset tool or python script available?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I wrote a tool for this in C# about 5 years ago but something may have come up since then. There is *snap* and *integrate* geoprocessing tools but they pay no attention to angles.. is it possible to get the red dots and put them higher on the snap priority? of course that would mean the green ends snap also to the red dots which is hardly ideal!